# Is there a way to view an old version of a Workshop Module in “Edit mode” without reverting to it?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I need to review an old configuration of a Workshop module but the module is in production and I do not want to break it for users while I review it. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not direct way within the original module, but here is a workaround where you duplicate the older version of the module:

1. Make sure the  “Automatically publish when saving” toggle switch is “Off” [image]
2. Revert to your desired version (won’t be published so won’t affect users in “View Mode”)
3. Make a copy of the module so you have the old version that you can review. [image]
4. Revert back to the new version